# How to use time series in c3.js chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series, linechart, c3.js

I need to draw a line chart based on time-series.I am using c3.js to plot my chart.I followed [this link](http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html) to achieve my requirement.

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            x: 'x',
            xFormat: '%Y',
            columns: [
                ['x', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015','2016'],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 400],
                ['data2', 830, 1200, 1100, 1400, 1150, 1250, 1500],
            ],
            axes: {
                data2: 'y2'
            },

        },

        axis: {
            x: {

                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%Y'
                    }
            },
            y2: {
                show: true
            }
        },
   });
```

This code works fine.

But i have a problem when I'm using the time series, my chart does not showing properly.

How do i achieve my requirement.I need to plot bulk data using time series with data-time-seconds.

**My requirement is:**

```
['x', '2013-01-01 12:00:00', '2013-01-02 12:00:05', '2013-01-03 12:00:10', '2013-01-04 12:00:15', '2013-01-05 12:00:20', '2013-01-10 12:00:25', '2013-01-15 12:00:30', '2013-02-15 12:00:35'],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 400],
                ['data2', 830, 1200, 1100, 1400, 1150, 1250, 1500],

       axis: {
            x: {

                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
                    }

            },
            y2: {
                show: true
            }
        },
```

***X-axis value shown an NaN***. How to get appropriate result for my requirement.Thank you.

**This is my issue:**
  [image: This is my issue on chart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your data is fine. But you have missed the option to define the time format. You may need to add the `xFormat` property in your data object and give the correct format.

```
 var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            x: 'x',
            xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            columns: [
                ['x', '2013-01-01 12:00:00', '2013-01-02 12:00:05', '2013-01-03 12:00:10', '2013-01-04 12:00:15', '2013-01-05 12:00:20', '2013-01-10 12:00:25', '2013-01-15 12:00:30', '2013-02-15 12:00:35'],
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 400, 200],
                ['data2', 830, 1200, 1100, 1400, 1150, 1250, 1500, 300],
            ],
            axes: {
                data2: 'y2'
            },

        },

        axis: {
            x: {

                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                        rotate: -90
                    }
            },
            y2: {
                show: true
            }
        },
   });
```

Notice the `xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` option. Actually that's what you have missed. Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/fyL5bt56/).

Hope it helps!!

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal Can you use timeseries and also data from csv? I have lots of data so I'm getting it from csv (url: 'data.csv') but I also want to use a time series with 12 hours interval and the total interval is 5 days. I tried many things but it doesn't work. It seems like I either have to use data from the same script (not csv) in order to use timeseries. Please help